# How to log parameters from generic function

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Given the following code:

```
int result = Execute(() => Foo(1, 2));

public int Foo(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

public T Execute<T>(
    Func<T> function)
{
    Console.Write(function.Method.Name + ": " + string.Join(", ", params));
    return function();
}
```

Is it possible to get the parameters? So the output would read something like:

"Foo: 1, 2"

Comment: Short answer: no

Comment: Long answer: yes. This is achievable through "aspect oriented frameworks". This solution involves injection of code through attribute marks on your methods. Another approach to use expression tree: Execute<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression) and parse it yourself to extract input parameters. This solution do not involve foreign frameworks, but do not cover all function calls entirely.

Comment: log them in the function that uses them (ie inside Foo) ?

Comment: If you changed `Func<T> function` to `MethodInfo` you can do this via `Reflection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Using expression tree. But beware, it does not cover all cases (chained invokations like LINQ, etc). It always can be arranged to cover those cases, but this method will become gigantic pile of garbage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int result = Execute(() => Foo(1, 2));
    }

    public static int Foo(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    public static T Execute<T>(Expression<Func<T>> function)
    {
        var call = function.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        var values = new List<object>();
        var obj = call.Object == null ? null : Expression.Lambda(call.Object).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
        foreach (var arg in call.Arguments)
        {
            var value = Expression.Lambda(arg).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
            values.Add(value);
        }
        LogMethodCall(call.Method.Name, values);
        return (T)call.Method.Invoke(obj, values.ToArray());
    }

    public static void LogMethodCall(string methodName, IEnumerable<object> args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", methodName, string.Join(",",args.Select(x=> x.ToString())));
    }
}
```

It will print out:

> Foo: 1,2

You can also log output and object of invokation in this example.

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you. I'll have to educate myself on using Expressions like this. Any concerns about performance? Or does the compiler essentially evaluate LINQ like this behind the scenes?

Comment: Performance is poor. Deal with it or explicitly write logging.